# show div one time per ip/24hs not work in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, cookies

I'm working on this code .. and works in all browsers, except in chrome.
I want to show a div(A) 1 time per IP every 24 hours. After displaying that div(A), I want to show another div(B) every time that ip visit my page.
This is my code

```
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/raw/master/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">                                         
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if( $.cookie('showOnlyOne') ){
            //it is still within the day
            //hide the div
            $('#showOnlyOnceADay').hide();
            $('#showothertimes').show();
        } else {
            //either cookie already expired, or user never visit the site
            //create the cookie
            $.cookie('showOnlyOne', 'showOnlyOne', { expires: 1 });

            //and display the div
            $('#showOnlyOnceADay').show();
            $('#showothertimes').hide();
        }
    });
    </script>     
</head>
<body>
    <div id="showOnlyOnceADay">
      Div(A)
    </div>
    <div id="showothertimes">
     Div(B)
    </div>
</body>
```

In Chrome shows the two div at the same time always. What's the problem? Thank you!

Comment: what is in your console?

Comment: I would like to think that `$.cookie('showOnlyOne')` creates the cookie with no value so you may not be able to validate it in the condition so try `if( $.cookie('showOnlyOne') == 'showOnlyOne' )`

Comment: console -Refused to execute script from 'https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/raw/master/jquery.cookie.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. posi.php:1
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'cookie' -                         It is a problem with the cookie. It's the first time I work with cookies. I was reading and many do not understand about local cookies.

Comment: What is this question all about ? Duplicating ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19918221/show-full-page-div-overlay-once-a-day-ip  ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are linking to the raw version of the javascript file on github. This is not being served with the correct MIME type, so you'll need to download it and serve it yourself. Github raw is not a CDN.

Are you developing this on your local machine? If so, Chrome does not accept cookies over the file protocol. You can either enable them by starting Chrome with a flag, or test it over HTTP using a web server somewhere. More information can be found here:

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/issues/231

Also, just to point out that technically your code will not be working by IP address as cookies are stored per machine and per browser as well as easily cleared and circumvented. Aside from this, your markup for both divs is all still available in the source and could be easily viewed with dev tools. If security (or rather the enforceability of your rule) is a concern you should think about moving the cookie code to the server side and only writing the appropriate div to the browser.

Comment: See the first sentence I've added to the answer then. From your console, it sounds like you need to download the `jquery.cookie.js` file, upload it to your server and change your script tag to reflect the new location.

Comment: Polly.. thanks.. download and upload it to my server .. WORKS!! It was very easy .. I'm very noob with cookies

Comment: Looking at your test site, it doesn't work on IE11 either. You need to update the line `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/raw/master/jquery.cookie.js"></script>` to reflect the location of the file on your server.

Comment: Thanks again .. was modifying the original file, not the test. Try it now .. WORKS!