# show full page div overlay once a day/ip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I need to show the "div overlay" once a day per IP... The overlay div shown for 5 seconds and then closes. I need to display only once and then not. This is the code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function toggleOverlay(){
var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
var specialBox = document.getElementById('specialBox');
overlay.style.opacity = .8;
if(overlay.style.display == "block"){
    overlay.style.display = "none";
    specialBox.style.display = "none";
} else {
    overlay.style.display = "block";
    specialBox.style.display = "block";
}
    }
</script>

<script>
  function timerdiv()
   {
   setTimeout(function(){return toggleOverlay()},5000);
   }
</script>


<body Onload="toggleOverlay();timerdiv();">

<!-- Start Overlay -->
<div id="overlay"></div>
<!-- End Overlay -->
<!-- Start Special Centered Box -->
<div id="specialBox">

 TEST Overlay BOX

</div>

 <!-- Start Special Centered Box -->
 <!-- Start Normal Page Content -->

<div id="wrapper">        

  Hello World!

</div>

 </body>
```

I have this code .. I have changed but I can not run properly.. Keep showing the overlay div on every visit

```
<script type="text/javascript"        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">                                         
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if( $.cookie('showOnlyOne') ){
            //it is still within the day
            //hide the div
            $('#overlay').hide();

        } else {
            //either cookie already expired, or user never visit the site
            //create the cookie
            $.cookie('showOnlyOne', 'showOnlyOne', { expires: 1 });

            //and display the div
            $('#overlay').show();

        }
    });
    </script>
```

EDIT:

Ok ... after to fight with the code for several hours. I found the solution, share it here in case someone serves in the future.

```
<head>

<style type="text/css">
div#overlay {
display: none;
z-index: 2;
background: #000;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
text-align: center;
opacity: 0.8;
}
div#specialBox {
display: none;
position: relative;
z-index: 3;
margin: 150px auto 0px auto;
width: 500px; 
height: 300px;
background: #FFF;
color: #000;
 }
div#wrapper {
position:absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 20%;
padding-left:24px;
  }
     </style>


  <script type="text/javascript"src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">                                         
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if( $.cookie('showOnlyOne') ){
            //it is still within the day
            //hide the div
           $('#overlay').hide();
          $('#specialBox').hide();
        } else {
            //either cookie already expired, or user never visit the site
            //create the cookie
            $.cookie('showOnlyOne', 'showOnlyOne', { expires: 1 });

            //and display the div
          $('#overlay').show();
          $('#specialBox').show();
          $('#specialBox').delay(3200).fadeOut(300);
          $('#overlay').delay(3200).fadeOut(300);
        }
    });
    </script>



 </head>
 <body>

 <!-- Start Overlay -->
 <div id="overlay"></div>
 <!-- End Overlay -->
 <!-- Start Special Centered Box -->
 <div id="specialBox">

 TEST Overlay BOX

 </div>

 <!-- Start Special Centered Box -->
  <!-- Start Normal Page Content -->

 <div id="wrapper">        

 Hello World!

 </div>

 </body>
```

The error in my own code was that did the same with two different script at the same time .. if there "Milche Patern" would have seen the code had realized much faster than me and had not lost time insisting that this question was the same as my previous question or saying "one time per 24h = once a day". But always I'll find people who like wasting time and wasting our time

Comment: Where is your cookie-reading/process function ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [show div one time per ip/24hs not work in chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19806877/show-div-one-time-per-ip-24hs-not-work-in-chrome)

Comment: "With cookies would be enough .. but not how." Are you asking if you could use cookies as part of the solution to do it. If so, that would be one way of keeping track of whether or not it had been previously done in that day. "but not how." I assume you're saying you don't want to be shown how but simply wanted a yes or no answer.  What are the "code"?

Comment: Milche Patern - in my previous question, was to show div once a day and it was a temporary problem with chrome. This is to run a script once a day, the code is totally different. Try to use the code from the previous question and I can not make it work

Comment: Terry - You're right, the question is poorly made. Now I correct it, what I want is the code to use cookies to run once a day the script.

Comment: Well, i AM confused in between ( show div one time per ip/24hs not work in chrome ) and ( show full page div overlay once a day/ip ) [one time per 24h  =  once a day]

Comment: Milche Patern- ok .. the words are synonymous. But the code does not work. In the previous question did not work in Chrome and thanks to Polly resolved. In this question, I try to implement the code of the cookies from the previous question with a script overlay and does not work and still shows the overlay again and again .. then not if the problem is in the script of cookies or the overlay or at all and I have to use another script